# Moving photo library from an iPhone to another iPhone via Computer

Tags: iphone, photos.app, migration, migration-assistant

I need to migrate and merge the contents of 2 old iPhones (lets call them **i1** and **i2**) to a new iPhone (**i_new**).

iPhones have built-in migration functionality, but AFAIK it doesn't allow to move stuff from multiple iPhones onto a single device.

So, I am planning to migrate the contents of one older iPhone **i1** to **i_new** with that tool and then move the stuff from the other one (**i2**) to **i_new** manually. Specifically: Notes, photos & videos, safari tabs.

I can access the photos on **i2** from a computer (within DCIM folder) using a USB cable.

My question is:
If I move the contents of **i2**'s DCIM to a PC, what would be the best way to add these photos to the **i_new** such that **i_new** would be able to accept them in its Photos App and properly sort them by the date taken within its "camera roll"?

Can I copy them from PC to **i_new**'s DCIM, or is iPhone's storage read-only when connected via USB as a "flash drive"?

Also, are all photos and videos from the Photos App located within DCIM, or are there any photos/vids hidden elsewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write photos to an iPhone except through the syncing mechanism exposed in Finder & iTunes.

Your best bet will be to enable iCloud Photos on each device and allow them to sync & merge, then disable iCloud Photos.

Comment: "Finder": I don't have a Mac.
"iCloud sync": I have more than 5 gigabytes of photos/videos on each old iphone. Will it be able to sync if the iCloud capacity is only 5 GB?

Comment: I said Finder & iTunes because on Windows it uses iTunes and on Mac it uses Finder. If you don't have Finder, you'll use iTunes.

Comment: That being said, photos synchronized using iTunes are read-only on the phone which in most cases isn't preferred.

Comment: If you have more than 5GB of photos, no. You can pay 99¢ for one month to upload and download all the photos, but I understand it's not ideal.

Comment: I guess "not ideal" comes with owning an Apple device...